# Does $x^x$ ever overtake $e^{x^2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I feel like it should, but I cannot prove it.  If it does, how can we find the precise value of $x$ for which $x^x$ overtakes the other?

Answer (score 14):

No. $x\ln x < x^2\ \forall\ x > 0$, and $\exp(x \ln x) = x^x$.

Answer (score 4):

Raise both sides to the power of $1/x$
$$x^x = e^{x^2} \implies x = e^x$$ 
Since it's well known that $e^x > x+1 >x$ we are done, as we see that we have no points in common and that $e^{x^2}> x^x$

Answer (score 3):

(I assume this problem is restricted to real, positive values of $x$)

It doesn't overtake it - $e^{x^2}$ is always larger.

Proof: (for $x > 0$)

\begin{align}
x &> \ln x \\
x^2 &> x \ln x \\
e^{x^2} &> x^x
\end{align}